# How do I have my control panel in English but my site locale to Dutch?

Tags: localization

I prefer my cp in English but I've noticed that it also sets the locale to "en_us" for the entire site. I need that locale to be "nl" since the site is in Dutch. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Craft Pro, you can go to your account's profile page where you can set your user's preferred language to English and the CP will display in English.

Comment: Is this pro only? Not seeing that setting in the client edition.

Comment: Right... you'd need Pro for that.  Will update the answer.

Comment: The same reason why adding a define locale statement to index.php isn't working either I guess?

Comment: Most likely... yeah.

Comment: Is it possible to have the CP in English without actually installing the en_us content locale? I'm running a site w/ content in Norwegian and I also prefer having the CP in English. However even if I specifically set my sections to target Norwegian only, Craft renders the language select dropdown above all index tables. When there's no actual content in English, that can be confusing. I tried setting the the 'defaultCpLanguage' to 'en' without actually having the English locale installed, which – oddly enough – does render the CP in English, but then my Norwegian content is invisible :)

Comment: @mmikkel haven't had coffee yet, so that could explain it, but I'm not following.  Can you hit up support@buildwithcraft.com explaining what you're looking for?

Comment: Cheers @BradBell – just sent you an email. In short, I'm looking to render the CP in a locale that isn't installed as a _content locale_. The email explains further. Also, turning on your computer before coffee? Reckless :)

Comment: I too would like to see this as an option - simply stated: I prefer my CP in English _without_ having to install an english locale.

Answer (score 4):

This solutions works for any locale, even if you don't have it installed as a front-end locale.
It also works for Personal or Client Craft installs.

Add a translations file into craft/translations/xx.php named after the currently selected user locale or system locale for
Craft Personal installs and use this code to include any locale's translations you want. You can also customize it
further by overwriting select translations:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

if (craft()->request->isCpRequest())
{
    $en = (include '../craft/app/translations/en.php');
    $custom = array(
        'Globals' => 'I freak out!',
    );

    return array_merge($en, $custom);
}

return [];
```

Comment: One downside of this approach: it doesn't override plugin translations (if you don not include them aswell).

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the snippet a bit. For me as Admin and Developer it's urgent to have it in English. But we figured out that clients want rather the native language. I think it's fine in this way.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

if (craft()->request->isCpRequest())
{
    if (craft()->userSession->isAdmin())
    {
        return (include '../craft/app/translations/en_gb.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $de = (include '../craft/app/translations/de.php');
        $custom = array(
            //'Globals' => 'I freak out!',
        );

        return array_merge($de, $custom);
    }
}

return [];
```